# How to get curly braces with Norwegian MacBook Pro keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-layout, macbook

Im having trouble with my keyboard layout. I have a MacBook Pro (June 2006) with 13.10 installed. I choose Norwegian Machintosh as keyboard layout, but I cant figure out how to create the third level characters, like curly braces.

It also seems that pipe is mapped to the key left of 1, so I have no idea where to find apostrophe.

The layout in the "Keyboard Layout Chart" doesnt even look like my keyboard.

How can I get a correct keyboard layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that keyboard mapping / configuration has changed in 13.10, and the "right" way of doing this would be:

1. Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`
2. And on page four choose which button you want to use for third level (*Left Alt* for me)

This give me similar keyboard mapping for third and fourth level as in Mac OS X.

You can also do this through the System Settings | Keyboard | Shortcut Tab | Typing. 
And change the *Alternative Characters Key* to *Left Alt*.

Comment: Hakon, I tried to fix this problem using your solution and i think i effed up. I on longer have the three last chacaters ae oe aa, is there a way to reset the settings i did in sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration... pls help

Comment: It sounds like you didn't choose a Norwegian keyboard layout during configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I used *lxkeymap* under Lubuntu 13.10.

```
sudo apt-get install lxkeymap
sudo lxkeymap
```

**Tools > Show/Hide Profiles > Options > Key to switch to third level > right windows button**

(unsure of the exact English translation for the last two points)

The right windows key corresponds to the right apple key. Now everything works for me.